# Can I group by property and map to new object in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Hi I have an array of objects where the category and sub category details are in the same object. So its like,

```
public class MyObject {
    String categoryCode;
    String categeoryCodeDescription;
    String subCategoryCode;
    String subCategoryCodeDescription;

    public MyObject(String categoryCode, String categeoryCodeDescription, String subCategoryCode, String subCategoryCodeDescription) {
        this.categoryCode = categoryCode;
        this.categeoryCodeDescription = categeoryCodeDescription;
        this.subCategoryCode = subCategoryCode;
        this.subCategoryCodeDescription = subCategoryCodeDescription;
    }
}

List<MyObject> collection = new ArrayList<MyObject>;
collection.add(new My Object("A1", "descA1", "A1A", "descA1A"));
collection.add(new My Object("A1", "descA1", "A1B", "descA1B"));
collection.add(new My Object("A1", "descA1", "A1C", "descA1C"));
collection.add(new My Object("A2", "descA1", "A2A", "descA2A"));
collection.add(new My Object("A2", "descA1", "A2B", "descA2B"));
```

Can you group by category code but map to an object including the description at the same time. So if I have two classes like..

```
public class Category {
    String categoryCode;
    String categoryDesc;
    public Category (String categoryCode, String categoryDesc) {
        this.categoryCode = categoryCode;
        this.categoryDesc = categoryDesc;
    }
}

public class SubCategory {
    String subCategoryCode;
    String subCategoryDesc;
    public SubCategory (String subCategoryCode, String subCategoryDesc) {
        this.subCategoryCode = subCategoryCode;
        this.subCategoryDesc = subCategoryDesc;
    }
}
```

..and I want to group the collection list into a `Map<Category,List<SubCategory>>`. I can group on the category code but I can't see how to create a new category instance as the map key. This may not be possible in a one liner.

```
Map<String, List<MyObject>> map = collection.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getCategoryCode));
```

Comment: `Collectors.mapping` will strike again...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done if you chain a `mapping` collector to `groupingBy`.

You use `mapping()` to transform the `MyObject` instances to `SubCategory` instances.

```
Map<Category,List<SubCategory>> map =
    collection.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(mo -> new Category(mo.getCategoryCode(),mo.getCategoryDesc()),
                                                      Collectors.mapping(mo->new SubCategory(mo.getSubCategoryCode(),mo.getSubCategoryDesc()),
                                                                         Collectors.toList())));
```

Note that `Category` will have to override `equals` and `hashCode` in order for this grouping to work.

Comment: With the same implementation, I am getting the duplicate values in SubCategory. I have overridden equals and hashcode method for one field in Category (In my case its id).

Comment: @DeskToDevelop after further thought, this code doesn't prevent duplicate SubCategory values. The OP's example simply had no duplicate SubCategories.

Comment: @DeskToDevelop you can override equals and hashCode in SubCategory class too, and eliminate the duplicates by changing the output to `Map<Category,Set<SubCategory>>`, and changing `toList()` to `toSet()`. But you can still get the same SubCategory associated with two different Categories.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this via the `toMap` collector taking a merge function:

```
Map<Category, List<SubCategory>> result = collection.stream()
                .collect(toMap(e -> new Category(e.getCategoryCode(), e.getCategeoryCodeDescription()),
                        v -> new ArrayList<>(singletonList(new SubCategory(v.getSubCategoryCode(), v.getSubCategoryCodeDescription()))),
                        (l, r) -> { l.addAll(r); return l; }));
```

This assumes you Category class has overriden the equals and hashcode methods as follows:

```
class Category {
    ...
    ... // properties + getters + constructors etc..
    ...

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Category category = (Category) o;
        return Objects.equals(categoryCode, category.categoryCode);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(categoryCode);
    }

}
```

to better readability you could extract the `keyMapper`, `valueMapper` and the `merge` function to different functions as follows:

```
private static List<SubCategory> valueMapper(MyObject v) {
        return new ArrayList<>(singletonList(new SubCategory(v.getSubCategoryCode(), v.getSubCategoryCodeDescription())));
}

private static List<SubCategory> merge(List<SubCategory> l, List<SubCategory> r) {
    l.addAll(r);
    return l;
}

private static Category keyMapper(MyObject e) {
     return new Category(e.getCategoryCode(), e.getCategeoryCodeDescription());
}
```

Then you can do:

```
 Map<Category, List<SubCategory>> result = collection.stream()
                .collect(toMap(Main::keyMapper,
                        Main::valueMapper,
                        Main::merge));
```

Where `Main` is the class containing the `keyMapper`, `valueMapper` and `merge` methods.